# CSS error: 'Could not find the original style sheet'

Tags: html, css, flask, stylesheet

I'm facing this issue loading my CSS stylesheets. For reference, here is my current folder layout:

[image]

I am having problem loading the stylesheets for recs.html. In my text editor, the code is as such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript>
```

The stylesheet for index.html works just fine, as it loads from assets-index perfectly. However, it doesn't seem to work for recs.html (even after I changed changed the folder name and the corresponding html code, e.g. assets-recs).

Can someone advise? Thank you!

Oh yes, if it helps, I am trying to run it on Flask, and on my Python script, the code is as such:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='',
            static_folder='template',
            template_folder='template')
```

The directory you see in the above screenshot is the "template" folder itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try flipping the two - eg..

```
<link href="assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Also remove the "/".

Answer (score 0):

If index.html just work fine with the stylesheet path than copy paste it from there over to your recs.html .

The html to your stylesheet path should look like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
```

You are using "/" at the end of yours "/>". Thats also not correct html.